# Stop command prompt from getting closed after executing a batch file

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd

I used Shell command from Excel VBA to run a certain .bat file. The CMD appears but exits automatically after all lines were executed. I've added the PAUSE command a the end of the bat. file but it's not working. How to stop command prompt from getting automatically closed?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the /K switch to prevent exiting after running the batch file like this:

cmd /K "path to batch file including file name and extension"

e.g.

```
    cmd /K "C:\FOLDER\BATCH FILE.BAT"
```

or

```
    cmd /K "C:\FOLDER\BATCH FILE.CMD"
```

Obviously that won't reveal any faults with your batch code, but it won't exit after running - much the same as running the batch file from the command line.

Definitely add some ECHO output lines to indicate progress as it runs and troubleshoot.  Perhaps post the file here for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the command prompt and running the batch file. It is possible that the the dos shell is encountering an error and closing. If the error comes before the execution reaches Pause command, it will not pause for you to read the error and it immediately closes off.

If that doesn't work out, check if you have any exit commands in any of the branches. Alternatively, place echo statements at different places and check if the execution control reaches these echos. This way you can find out if your script if ending at some other branch.

Comment: Thanks for that quick response Govardhan!
When I ran the .bat file from the cmd prompt, it is not closing, but the words "press any key to continue..." is not displayed.

Comment: Try putting Echo at different places and find out where the execution is stopping. See if there is any intermediary Exit. It would be easy for us to come up with suggestions if you can place the batch file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

While perhaps not actually answering the posted question, I stumbled upon this question in a search to a very related-question.  I was also trying to stop a command prompt from closing as it was erroring out and closing immediately.  For me, it was sufficient for me to view the output as what I really wanted was to be able to see the error in order to debug it.

The solution I found was to pipe the output of the command prompt into a text file, like so:

```
MyScript.bat >> text.txt
```

This allowed me to see the error I was getting.